# Hooking offset from IDA throws Access Violation

Tags: function-hooking

I've been trying to hook a function using Detours 1.5, but when `DetourFunction()` is called, it throws access violation.

This is the original function:

```
int greeter(char *name) {
    printf_s("%s, %s!\n", greetings[rand() % ((int) sizeof(greetings) / (int) sizeof(greet_t))], name);
    int rerun = strcmp("Gabriel", name);
    if (!rerun) printf_s("Have a nice day!\n");
    return rerun;
}
```

With the program compiled and running properly, I used IDA Pro to see the [trace and found my function](https://gist.github.com/gfreivasc/874fa4e780b06538de35d9c559f74fbe) beginning on address `0x004010B0`.
Then I set the variable `DWORD orig_greeter = 0x4010B0`. And wrote the following code:

```
#include "sky.h"

int myGreeter(char* name);
int (__cdecl* origGreeter)(char*);

bool __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID pvReserved) {
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        // Start Hook Sub-Routine
        origGreeter = (int (__cdecl*)(char*))DetourFunction((PBYTE)orig_greeter, (PBYTE)myGreeter);
        origGreeter("sir");
    }   
    return true;
}

int myGreeter(char* name) {
    printf_s("You've been hooked, %s!", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Once DetourFunction tries to access the given offset it throws Access Violation and the function is not hooked. What am I missing?

[Edits removed. No relevant for the question]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I was considering the base address given by IDA Pro instead of process actual base address.

The IDA Base was `0x400000`, thus the offset really was `0x10B0`. Once I updated `orig_greeter` to this value, I call it as follows.

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
origGreeter = (int (__cdecl*)(char*))DetourFunction((PBYTE)hModule+orig_greeter, (PBYTE)myGreeter);
```

The code itself still doesn't behave as expected, but it detours properly. The callstack showed it called `myGreeter` when it was supposed to. Therfore, I consider this question answered.